# Determine if being on honor roll gives an advantage in being assigned to the math class

Tags: statistics

> Andrew believes the honor roll students at his school have an unfair advantage in being assigned to the math class they request. He asked 500 students at his local school "Did you get the math class you requested?"
>   Help Andrew determine if all students at his school have an equal opportunity to get the math class they requested.
>
> Honor roll: 215 received the math class; 80 did not
>   Not on Honor roll: 125 received math class, 80 did not

*Is the formula $A\cup B$? are they asking if i have to see if they are independent?

Comment: that is all they gave me. Are they leaving something out?

Comment: i think the question is correctly stated and yes you just need to check for independence using chi-squared test.

Answer (score 2):

Use Pearson's chi-squared test for independence http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Test_of_independence.

Here's our tables,
$$
\begin{array}{|l|c|c|}
\hline 
\bf{Observed} & \textrm{math} & \textrm{non-math} \\
\hline 
\textrm{honor} & 215 & 80 \\
\hline 
\textrm{non-honor} & 125 & 80 \\
\hline 
\end{array}
\qquad 
\begin{array}{|l|c|c|}
\hline 
\bf{Expected} & \textrm{math} & \textrm{non-math} \\
\hline 
\textrm{honor} & 200.6 & 94.4 \\
\hline 
\textrm{non-honor} & 139.4 & 65.6 \\
\hline 
\end{array}
$$
where, for example, $(215+125)\cdot(215+80)/500 = 200.6$. Hence,
$$
\chi^2 \approx \frac{(215-200.6)^2}{200.6}+\frac{(80-94.4)^2}{94.4}+\frac{(125-139.4)^2}{139.4}+\frac{(80-65.6)^2}{65.6}=7.87
$$

Now, we go to a chi-squared table with $1$ degrees of freedom. At the $95\%$ level the critical value is $3.84$, we reject the null-hypothesis of independence so it does not give an advantage to honors students.

Comment: Since this is a [chi-squared test in table format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Chi-squared_test_for_independence_and_homogeneity_in_tables), this example has only 1 degree of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

P(Honor Student gets requested class) = 215/(215+80) = 215/295 = .729

P(Not Honor Student gets requested class) = 125/(125+80) = 125/205 = .610

Honor students are more likely to get the math class they requested.  Whether that is an unfair advantage is a subjectiuve question.

Comment: They might also be expecting some confidence level that the first is greater than the second, assuming these are random samples.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Use Proportion Differences Hypothesis Testing

p1 = Proportion of Honor Students getting their request of Math Class
p2 = Proportion of Non Honor Students getting their request of Math Class

H0 :  p1=p2

H1 :  p1 Not equal to p2

Pooled Sample proportion = (p1*n1+p2*n2)/(n1+n2)

p1 = 215/295 = .729
n1 = 295

p2=125/205 = .61
n2 = 205

p = (215+125)/500 = .68

SE = SQRT(p*(1-p)*(1/n1+1/n2)) = SQRT(.68*.32*(1/295+1/205)) = .042

Z statistic = (p1-p2)/SE = (.729-.61)/.042 = 2.833

It is a two tailed test and hence z - critical = 1.96 at Alpha = 0.05

Reject Ho if Z>=1.96

Here Z-statistic = 2.833 >=1.96

Hence We are rejecting the null hypothesis and conclude that there is sufficient evidence to say that Honor and Non Honor students do not get an equal opportunity to get the math class they requested.

Thanks

Satish